# Is it wrong to define ID in body tag for CakePHP?

Tags: html, cakephp

I am working on a project in which I define `ID` inside of a `<body>` tag. For different pages I define different `IDs`, & I always follow this structure for my all projects. But in our new project which is in CakePHP, my developer said to me that I should never use `ID` inside the body tag for a CakePHP project.

When I asked him why, he said because we can generate `ID` through CakePHP.

I don’t know so much about CakePHP, but I think we can define `ID` inside the body tag for CakePHP & other languages also.

Please provide some links or articles & your suggestions about it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what the question is here. Yes, you can put an id attribute on the `<body>`. Yes you can do it dynamically. No, Cake doesn't really care either way. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: i want to know 'are we can give id manually in cakephp?' because my developer said please remove ID's form your html markup

Comment: @deceze; please provide some links so i can explain to him thanks :)

Comment: I don't think anybody has ever written anything about this because there's nothing to write about really. The best I could do is a Google search, which I'll leave up to you. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define id's in your HTML mark-up that's not a problem. But from your question it looks like you are defining id's as an attribute to body tag?

Well you can define id's in body tag. but the problem is in cakePHP you have layouts which usually contain the wrapping HTML of your views, like header, footer etc. So you can not manually define static id's inside body tag for different pages, well you can but then you won't be using layouts. 
What your developer telling you I guess is the use of (uuid) unique id's a feature provided by cakePHP to generate unique id's for DOM elements.

you can generate id's via `uuid(string $object, mixed $url)` function in your views.

To learn more visit : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1091/uuid

Comment: You certainly CAN add id's for different pages, using exactly the same technique as you do for page titles:

in controller:

    $this->set('bodyId'=>'my-body-id');

in view:

    <body id='<?php echo $bodyId ?>'>

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically add classes to your layout like so:

```
<?php
$classes = String::insert(':plugin :controller :action', array(
    'plugin'     => $this->plugin,
    'controller' => strtolower($this->name),
    'action'     => $this->action,
));
?>
<div id="content" class="<?php echo trim($classes); ?>">
    <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
</div>
```

This would allow you to namespace your CSS declarations:

```
.blog.posts.view h2 {
    /* ... */
}
```

Note: IE6 doesn't properly support chaining of multiple classes to select a single element, though there are some [Javascript](http://chicowebdesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/multiple-classes/) [shims](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) if you are still supporting it.